# Issue concatenating error.detailsDescription with any string in mule 4

Tags: dataweave, mule4

While handling error in mule 4, I tried using:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---

"Hello Team"
 
"Recodarti Order export job failed error is " ++ error.detailedDescription ++ 
 
"REP Sap Code is NULL please reverify the data and reprocessed the interface. 
Thank You"
```

but I'm getting a scripting error in the console. How can I concatenate a string with `error.detailsDescription`?

Answer (score 1):

Its possibly happening due to the incorrect script declaration.

Try below

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
"Hello Team \nRecodarti Order export job failed error is " ++ error.detailedDescription ++ "REP Sap Code is NULL please reverify the data and reprocessed the interface. \nThank You"
```

output

```
Hello Team 
Recodarti Order export job failed error is xxx REP Sap Code is NULL please reverify the data and reprocessed the interface. 
Thank You
```